# ubuntu install failed detect the available gpus and deal with any system changes. dell 5820 i9

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, radeon, gpu

I have a new Dell 5820 i9 workstation. I am trying to load `ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` with USB drive.

The installation fails at:

> ubuntu install failed detect the available gpus and deal with any system changes

a Radeon Pro WX 5100 card is used.

Any help would be great.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did the self-verification complete; the SQUASHFS errors imply the media is faulty, or if VM your virtual machine has too little ram (from your description it's not a VM).  The squashfs also explain why details such as kernel modules (drivers) cannot be located.. ie. the squashfs errors to me are the issue that matters (as they tell you any other messages may not be trusthworthy)

Comment: I have tried this will 3 different usb drives. I have also created the boot usb on 2 different ubuntu servers I have running.

Comment: This machine has eight 32GB UDIMMs installed. All 8 slots are full. Thats 256gb ram. I think thats the most I have used on a server.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO prior to write? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  and if the media is fine on other boxes that tells you little unless they other boxes had identical hardware (thus read the same parts of the ISO.. unless the media validation passed on the other boxes; that for sure would imply it's an issue related to this box.. squashfs errors can occur due to insufficient RAM too; why it seems to impact VMs)

Comment: I will have not verified the ISO. I will check that now. Thanks

Comment: FYI: thet verification link was provided in my first duplicate link

Comment: you were right. The ISO was corrupted. I downloaded another ISO and install works now. Thanks very much !!

Answer (score 0):

The ISO was corrupted. I downloaded another ISO and install works now. Thanks very much  guiverc !!